ASP.NET Instrumentation for OpenTelemetry not filtering outgoing http requests triggered by filtered incoming one
We are using OpenTelemetry for .net 8 web api.
Here are the packages
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.6.0-rc.1" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.ElasticsearchClient" Version="1.0.0-beta.5" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.GrpcNetClient" Version="1.6.0-beta.3" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http" Version="1.6.0-beta.3" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Quartz" Version="1.0.0-alpha.3" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient" Version="1.6.0-beta.3" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.StackExchangeRedis" Version="1.0.0-rc9.12" />

The problem is following, we use AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation method where we configure Filter to filter out all incoming requests that don't meet our criteria including  /metrics.
 options.Filter = x => x.IsApiHttpRequest() || x.IsGrpcRequest();
 options.Enrich = (activity, operationName, target) =>
 {
     if (target is not HttpResponse httpResponse)
     {
         return;
     }

 };

The problem is that such requests are successfully filtered out but all the outgoing http requests triggered by /metrics endpoint itself are still reported.
If our understanding is correct this filter is based on spec of IsRecording that should be marking all child spans in a such way that they aren't reported to otel anymore.
Can someone help with is?
We tried to filter all white-noise requests and it's child spans with aspnetcoreInstrumentation, we expected that all irrelevant requests would be filtered out from otel. The root span is filtered but it's child spans are still reported.

Filtering doesn't set the sampling flag so you won't stop the child activity with that. Look at the Sampler instead.
